# What is the ideal way to deploy pods to the artifactory?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, artifactory

Disclaimer - *I am very new to cocoapods. This might be a very silly question for most ios developers.*

The artifactory documentation [link](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/CocoaPods+Repositories) for uploading **cocoapods** is quite explanatory and easily understandable. I have followed the steps and I have tried uploading a well known pod (**ABCustomUINavigationController**) to the my own local instance of artifactory.

The deployment section of the documentation says 
[image]

I am using the Web UI for deploying the pod (in .tar.gz format) to the artifactory. The way I've done that is:
[image]

***Is this the ideal way to deploy pods?*** Also, if I want to upload a xcodeproj (build output) of the pod along with the .podspec file, then how should I go about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I see you uploaded the pod itself under the `.specs` folder of your repo, this is actually where Artifactory keeps the `index` that the `pod` client later retrieves when you use `pod repo-art add` or `pod repo-art update`. Although there's no restriction as to *where* to put the pods themselves I would keep them out of the `.specs` folder to keep things organized for yourself.

As for build outputs - A CocoaPod typically contains source code (and perhaps other resources) that a project can include and not the output of the build of a project so I'm not sure what is the benefit of uploading extra content (such as build products) with it and separated from it.

In any case the way the `pod` client handles pods is by searching for a proper entry in the index (i.e. everything that's under `.specs` in your repo) that satisfies the required version defined in your project's `Podfile` and then using the address in that index file (which points back to `Artifactory` in our case) to download the required `Pod`.

So in other words, anything else you put in the repository which is not a tarballed pod is ignored both by Artifactory and by the `pod` client.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. So, if I've understood you correctly, I can only deploy the .podspec file to the artifactory under .specs in my repo? Please clarify!

Comment: You don't need to deploy the `.podspec` file as it's already contained in the `pod` (the `tar.gz` file) you uploaded, or at least it should be - that's the convention, and Artifactory extracts it for you and places it under the `.specs` folder --> all you need to do is deploy the `pod` and it will be automatically tagged and available to the client.  The place you upload *to* should not be the `.specs` folder though - choose some other location that suites you.

Comment: Thanks. I get it. Yes, I uploaded the entire pod in .tar.gz format and the .podspecs file automatically gets placed under the .specs folder. What I actually need to do is deploy the **.framework** file to the artifactory along with the .podspecs file instead of deploying the entire pod in the artifactory. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve with that, that's not how the `pod` client works...  the pod client downloads `pods`, opens them and does maybe other actions you defined in the `.podspec` file to integrate the code contained in it with your xcode project that wants to use the `pod`. it cannot process raw `.framework` files - only if they are part of a `pod`and you used the `use_frameworks!` directive for example.

Answer (score 3):

**For MAC users:**

***Step 1:***

```
brew install gnu-tar
```

*Reason:* As default mac uses `tar` for zipping and which has problems with jFrog artifactory

**Usage:**

```
gtar czvf swift-sdk.tar.gz *
gtar czvf testPOD.tar.gz testPOD/testPOD/* testPOD/testPOD.podspec
```

**Note:** Make sure unnecessary files not get zipped. For instance if `.git` present in zip, it creates lot of issues.

***Step 2:***

Follow official link and video
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/CocoaPods+Repositories#app-switcher

**Some of the useful commands:**

For add spec repo to the local machine:

`pod repo-art add cocoapods-local "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/pods/cocoapods-local"`

For repo update:

`pod repo-art update cocoapods-local`

Push artifacts to jFrog:

`curl -uadmin123:123456 -XPUT http://localhost:8081/artifactory/cocoapods-local/testPOD/0.1.0/ -T testPOD.tar.gz`

Cocoapod spec repo:

`source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'`

Point to spec repo in Podfile:

`plugin 'cocoapods-art', :sources => [
  'cocoapods-local'
]`

Comment: This is for deploying a local pod project for the first time. In case if i update the project how do i push the changes as a new version to artifactory?

Comment: The `gtar` thing baffled me when I found out that indeed the simple `tar` command wasn't generating an archive to Artifactory's liking.

Comment: @Rakesh you are rockstar!!